# Where does Panem's electricity come from?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108670/14710) to my question about Panem's population, it is assumed that the only source of electricity is the coal that is mined from District 12.  However, in the movies the rebels cut power to the Capital by blowing up a hydro-electric plant, implying that Panem has at least two sources of electricity.

Is there any canon information, aside from that scene, about where Panem's electricity actually comes from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Coal ≠ energy. In an industrialized world coal has many uses, and energy is just one possible use. Coal is instrumental in the production of steel, one of the most used metal alloys on earth, and with Panem's military I bet we find it uses quite a lot of steel to support. Steel is also instrumental in large buildings that cities contain (think the capital).

While we don't have a confirmed location for District 12, it's most likely located along the northern part of the Appalachian Mountains, which puts it in a prime area to mine bituminous coal, which is the kind of coal used in industrial purposes and not in electricity production.

> The bituminous coal fields of western Pennsylvania, western Maryland, southeastern Ohio, eastern Kentucky, southwestern Virginia, and West Virginia contain the sedimentary form of coal.
>
> **Steam coal** - also known as thermal coal - is mainly used in power generation.
>
> **Coking coal** - also known as metallurgical coal - is mainly used in steel production.
>
> Other important uses of coal include alumina refineries, paper
>   manufacturers, and the chemical and pharmaceutical industries. Several
>   chemical products can be produced from the by-products of coal.
>   Refined coal tar is used in the manufacture of chemicals, such as
>   creosote oil, naphthalene, phenol, and benzene. Ammonia gas recovered
>   from coke ovens is used to manufacture ammonia salts, nitric acid and
>   agricultural fertilisers. Thousands of different products have coal or
>   coal by-products as components: soap, aspirins, solvents, dyes,
>   plastics and fibres, such as rayon and nylon.

Also according to the wiki (which i will attempt to get book quotes to back up) [District 5](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/District_5) is

- the 3rd richest district
- runs approximately 15 power plants

Other than the large hydro-electric plant we see the rebels sabotage, it also has a solar plant named after President Snow, and seems to export its energy across the continent, which appears to be why District 12 (other side of the continent) has sporadically insufficient power.

Its also reasonable to assume that since district 13 had the knowledge and ability to create nuclear weapons, which is a far more indepth task then harnessing nuclear energy in a power plant, district 5 may also have been operating a number of nuclear power plants.

Some of this is referenced to [thecaptiol.pn](http://www.thecapitol.pn/) website hosted by lionsgate.

The Hunger Games Tribuite Guide, licensed by Lionsgate has this to say on district 5.

[image]

Comment: @KerrAvon yes out of the suspected 15 powerplants it appears the hydro electric plant was specifically running the capital.

Comment: Most of this doesn't attempt to answer the question, which is about *where  the electricity comes from*, not *what the coal is used for*. The last section does answer the question, but Wikia is not a reliable source!

Comment: @randal'thor the first portion is in regards to you speculator answer about coal as the single form of energy and basis for population count. the 2nd bit is about all the book has to offer.

Comment: @Himarm Surely the place for responding to an answer is in the comments? This question isn't asking about what D12's coal is used for. Have you got any canon (book) references for the stuff about D5?

Comment: Rand al'thor - he's answering this question which was asked by Dave Johnson and which independently refers to your answer. The response is entirely appropriate in my opinion, as it responds to the question as it is written.

Comment: @randal'thor http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ZIeR-VSLTgw/UldGV6_ooII/AAAAAAAAF_I/Y_5tDLPNcyY/s1600/Screen+Shot+2013-10-10+at+5.18.11+PM.png  this is an image of what thecapital.pn HAD hosted but their site is currently unusable because of how dumb it was designed

Answer (score 2):

District 10 also makes electricity through their solar panel fields however this is mainly used to supply power to the fences in the districts and the districts themselves

Comment: This is a nice find but your answer would be greatly improved if you [edit]ed to add in sources.